# List of subclass "master copies", looking for a better design

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

I recently worked on a small game project where the player would be granted a random item at a certain point. The items (about 50 or so) were implemented as sub-classes of a virtual `Item` interface. We needed a way to select one of those items randomly and give an *instance of the specific class* to the player.

Our solution was to create some container (e.g. `std::list`) and insert an instance of each item we implemented. The item implementations had to provide a copy constructor, so that we could just create a copy for the player who gets the item. Voilà!

The downside is clear: it's very easy to forget inserting an item, and being careless with the copy constructors can lead to bugs that are not so easy to track. Since it was prototype code we didn't bother too much, but I wonder if there is a prettier way. An ideal solution would include:

1. Automatic "registering" of items, somewhere.
2. A way to choose one item at random and instantiate it.
3. No need for writing copy constructors for each item.

Thanks for your hints and suggestions!

Daerst

Comment: what do you mean by automatic registering of items?

Comment: I would like an as-failsafe-as-possible way to register every new item in whichever place is used to choose a random one. With the current solution, it's easy to create a new item subclass, but never add it to the list of items.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a factory to create items. The factory will then also register the create item in the container. I'd like to use shared pointer for players! But that'd be up to you.

This way you can ensure that items will be created through a single interface. And also the common logic for inserting items etc. is implemented at a single place.

Answer (score 1):

There are details that are not clear in your question.  For example, based on my interpretation of your question it would seem that you are hard coding the specifics of your items?  Based on the assumption that you're current prototype is hard coding the details of your items for your game I would:

1. Separate the content from the code - This is important because changing content values will require you to recompile, or more importantly, expansion of the total number of items will soon become burdensome and error prone.
2. Create a generic class that represents an item with all of the appropriate fields necessary to populate this item class with the relevant details of the item.

2A. If your items do not have similar properties, you could use some sort of self-describing array of the custom aspects of the item.  For example, Item A is unique and has a flavour property.  You would have a a two dimensional array [1][2] with it's values being [1][1] = flavour [1][2] = blueberry.

1. Create a class that acts as a container for items.
2. In the container class, implement a method to instance a random item (pulling the details about the item from the database or other storage mechanism), and adding it to the containers collection of "loaded items" - effectively "registering" it. The two obvious benefits to having this container class is that once an item is loaded, and if you then choose another random item that happens to be one already loaded, you don't have to load it again and secondly, you are using less memory until the entire item set has been loaded.
3. In the container class, implement a method to copy an instanced item to the player class. - OR - create an interface in the container class that your player class implements to request a new random item - which would then call upon the method to instance a random item.

Hope this helps in your brainstorming!

Comment: Yes, since the majority of items have very distinct behavior we hardcoded most of them. That said, we wrote more generic classes for some kinds of items (Consumable, Melee weapons, Projectile weapons). Using a kind of data description, as you suggest, or even a scripting language would avoid the problem of instancing / copy constructing, but sure brings along its own set of problems or at least complexities. I'm currently thinking about a compromise solution using only one base item class and hard-coded lambda functions in the instances.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the items to the `vector` right inside the `constructor` of the `Item` class. That way you won't need to add every single item "by hand", they'll be added upon creation.
2. Instead of copying the items, make them **singleton** classes and instead of 'giving' the user an item, just use a pointer to a place inside your `vector`.

That being said, your problem is strictly connected with the bad design of the game. Items shouldn't be derived classes, but instances of a generic item class. But since other people already mentionned it, I don't think typing it once more would be any help to you :)